# Android ExpandableListView : two item per row

Tags: android, row, expandablelistview

Simple question :
I would like to know if it's possible to have two items per row when you expand the expandable listview.

If yes -> How ?

If no -> :(

Thx

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It can be done easily by **Coding**

Comment: Yes it's possible. Google for `android custom expandablelistview`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if is there a specific library for this, but I think you can simply create your custom adapter with a custom row layout and fill every row with two items instead of just one.

Example:

Row-Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:width="match-parent"
  android:height="wrap-content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/first"
    android:width="match-parent"
    android:height="wrap-content"/>

  <TextView android:id="@+id/second"
    android:width="match-parent"
    android:height="wrap-content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the adapter something like:

```
private ArrayList<MyItems> myItems;  //fill this with the constructor

@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup vg) 
{
  //initialize the layout inflater and other stuffs like textviews
  if(position % 2 == 0){
    //this is because you are grouping items by 2, so you only consider the first of the couple.
    textView1.setText(myItems.get(position).getText());
    textView2.setText(myItems.get(position+1).getText());
    //here tou can manage also the onclicklisteners for each item
  }
}
```

this is an idea, tell me if this can work.

PS: I wrote this by hand here, so there might be some writing error, in this case feel free to edit the answer :)

Comment: I will try something like that. Thanks you